# Google-Images Disocrd.js Not sending Images

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, google-image-search

Previously I had figured out how to send images, based on the arguments, now I have updated the command to a different command handler and it doesn't send anything. The error in the console says :

```
ErrorClass [HTTPError]: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
    at C:\Users\infec\Desktop\Uni Beta\node_modules\google-images\node_modules\got\index.js:123:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  host: 'www.googleapis.com',
  hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/customsearch/v1?q=summer&searchType=image&cx=91069a4e85b6cd0e0&key=AIzaSyCTOYK4lo7uEr59H___PPH5d7e3kAk3OnY',
  statusCode: 403,
  statusMessage: 'Forbidden'
}
```

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const GoogleImages = require('google-images');

module.exports = {
  name: 'pic',
  description: 'Sends A Picture Depending On Arguments',
  async run(client, message, args, cseid, apikeygoogle, prefix) {

    const client2 = new GoogleImages(cseid, apikeygoogle)

    var term = args.join(" ")

    if (term) {
      client2.search(`${term}`)
        .then(images => {
          const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
          message.channel.send({ files: [images[randomIndex].url] });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          message.channel.send('Error')
          console.log(err)
        })
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Your `.catch` does not pass on the error and instead you `console.log` the `error` object you've imported from a package called `console` (see the first line in your code). Change your `.catch` to `.catch((err) => {...` and then use `console.log(err)` to see what the actual error is from the GoogleImages client

Comment: I have added the error above